# DISTINCT optimization

Tags: sql, query-optimization

When optimizing this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Order FROM OrderItem
```

which plans would the different RDBMS engines build and which would be the most efficient?

Comment: I don't think there can be a serious answer to this.  "Which would be the most efficient" depends on all kinds of things (like the storage model) and I would hope that each engine would use a plan that is most efficient for it.

Comment: This is not a sincere question, it is part of an April Fool's Day joke (see http://explainextended.com/2011/04/01/shared-plan-and-algorithm-network-cache-spanc/)

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on the indexing and the database.

- In [sql server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) you can analyze the query plan in the GUI, or the SHOWPLAN_ALL keyword.
- In [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and [pgsql](http://www.digipedia.pl/pgsql/8.1/sql-explain.html) you can use the EXPLAIN keyword in SQL

So go ahead and try it out on the different servers using Identical schemas and find out for yourself!

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL` would use a loose index scan on an indexed field, and a temporary table or a `filesort` on an unindexed fied.

The other engines would use either a `SORT GROUP BY` or a `HASH GROUP BY`.

The former is usually more efficient on an indexed field, however, the index scanning overhead may be quite significant, so `Oracle` could prefer an `INDEX FULL SCAN` with a `HASH GROUP BY` over it.